# How can I get node red flow to start on boot

Tags: node-red, boot

I can see from posts how to get node red itself to start running on boot.  However, how can I lock in a particular flow that I want to run on the start up boot?

I guess I need to put the flow location into "settings" or something?

It's for my raspberry pi...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72592860/edit) the question to add a little more clarity here. Are you wanting to effectively make the flow read-only? Or just a way to set the flow ahead of the next reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I use the inject node with "inject once after 0.1 seconds" set at the start of the flow I want to run

Comment: Hello, Do you connect this node to anything or can be just some debug node? What is the idea on how this fixes the issue.